# How to remove old activities from backstack? (true way)

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm new to Android development and here's my problem: 
I have 2 activities: A and B.
From A, I call B via `startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class))` 
From B, I do some things and return to A the same way: `startActivity(new Intent(B.this, A.class))` 
However, when on new-A I press "Back" button, first I see B class and then the old (unchanged version) of A class. 
I've tried placing `finish();` inside `onPause()` method. However, then my Activity crashes on orientation change. 
How can I properly control activity backstack? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to reorder A in front of B? Or close B and update A?

Comment: I want new-A be the only activity in backstack. So pressing "Back" lead me to Home Screen

Comment: To understand magic of Stack see [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `startActivity` without any additional flags, you will create a new instance of the Activity specified. This means that your back stack ends up looking like this:

```
A -> B -> A(2)
```

You have two options:

First option, you can add flags on the Intent that instructs it to reorder A to the front if it is already present in the back stack. Note that this will not close B; you have to call `finish()` in B afterward.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startAcvitiy(intent);
finish();
```

Second option is to use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity` in A and have Activity B pass a result back to A. I think this is much cleaner and it gives you a very easy way to react to what happened when B was finished (e.g. you can update your UI). See [this guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) from the Android developers site.

Comment: in general it feels dirty/bad practice to explicitly call `finish()`, my preference is to rely on the framework to handle that for me.

Comment: But why? (oh I need more symbols to post)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with calling finish() to explicitly close an Activity. You need not wait for the framework to do it for you; in fact it may not do so for quite a long time if the framework doesn't kill your process in order to reclaim memory. I can think of numerous use cases for calling `finish()`, the most obvious being after you've called `setActivityResult(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Either [StartActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) or think about using fragments. If you need to jump between activities think about why you are doing this? If you are passing info between the two then there are a couple of options. Fragments give you the option and you can hold the data on the Activity that hosts the fragments or you can have a Singleton living in an Application class that you would extend.

Comment: One activity is just ListView of notes, and the other one is Note Editing activity. When I save it, I return to ListView

Answer (score 0):

Read about activity lifecycle - [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). You have to implement saving of instance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that rather than calling `startActivity` in to go back to `A`, you can just call instead `finish()`;. This will land you back on your previous `Activity`.

Alternatively you can accomplish the same if you use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Regarding the accepted answer's suggestion to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` - for your case it really doesn't matter. but in a slightly different case where you have A->B->C and you use REORDER to go back to A, you'd actually end up with a stack that looks like B->C->A. With CLEAR_TOP, you'd end up with just A. Point is, `REORDER` is meant to `REORDER`, `CLEAR_TOP` is supposed to pop the backstack. In your simple case they happen to accomplish the same, but in my opinion it's better practice to use the flags as they're intended.

Comment: Is using "FLAG.." more correct? I don't see the difference between these two options in Android Developer website